# Eclipse Indigo does not show Windows -> Preferences -> Java

Tags: eclipse, bdd, mockito

I want to use BDDMockito with Eclipse based on the existing Test template  to automatically generate the BDD style comments & statically imported BDDMockito members.To do that I need to set up the template from this location -

modify the template, navigate to Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates.

However, I am unable to see this option. 
Please suggest how can I view this.

Comment: How much of the path `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates` do you get? Specifically, is there a "Java" entry?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the textbox above the TreeView control on the left of the dialog, and type in "Templates", does this show you the Java Templates view in the expanded, filtered tree?